# Does "=+IF(...)" do anything in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am automating a large Excel spreadsheet for a customer and I keep coming across a strange construct in their formulas.  Virtually all of their `IF` functions have formulas that look like this:

```
=+IF(<cond1>,"text",IF(<cond2>,1,2))
```

Note the `+` at the beginning, immediately after the equals sign.  At first I thought it was spurious, but it sure is used extensively (hundreds of places).  Then I thought that maybe it was to force the result to be interpreted as a numeric by Excel, but most of the places that use it are `IF` functions that return non-numeric text for the majority of their result values.

Does anyone know if this actually does anything in Excel formulas?

(Excel 2007, if that matters)

Comment: The original author typed formulas with a `+` and Excel appends the `=`...a holdover from spreadsheet times gone by.  No functional difference between the two operators though!

Comment: Thanks Jacob (no relation, AFAIK :-)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as my knowledge with Excel itt doesn't do anything resorceful. It is mainly a leftover from the days of Lotus 123. It is quite harmless, and doesn't change the operation of the
formulas in any way so if its a possibility u need to ditch it its totally fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have converted a few Lotus 123 documents with the `+` appearing. A simple search (for `+`) and replace (with a blank) calms the OCD in all of us.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it is because `=` sign is too far from number pad and it is easier to use `+` sign when i want to enter a formula.